# in visual studio 12 can not open dialog box i.e. 1. add references - Browse. 2.Add new Project-BrowsePath

Tags: visual-studio-2012

in visual studio 12 can not open dialog box i.e.

1. add references - Browse.

2.Add new Project-BrowsePath.

I had already reseat all setiings of visual studio.

Comment: Got a solution, restart "TabletInputService" from task manager or from services.

Comment: Than don't forget to restart visual studio.

Comment: Write your comment as the answer, as this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps, its working,

1. open **task manger > services** or **services**
2. start **TabletInputService** Service (restart if already running)
3. restart Machine